# Python mapper reducer

Tags: python, hadoop

I am new to python and can't figure out why this code produces no error messages and no output.  It reads a web log file.

```
def mapper(key, line):
    parts = line.split("/")
    if len(parts) > 2:
        return parts[1], 1
    return None, 1

def reducer(key, values):
    return key, sum(values)

def main():
    data = {key,values}
    with open('apache.log', 'r') as logfile:
        for idx, line in enumerate(logfile):
            line = line.strip()
            key, val = mapper(idx, line)
            if key in data:
                data[key].append(val)
            else:
                data[key] = [val,]
        for key, values in data.items():
            print reducer(key, values)
```

Log file:

```
[31/Dec/1994:23:46:48 -0700] "GET 116.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 12053
remote - - [31/Dec/1994:23:50:42 -0700] "GET 2196.ps HTTP/1.0" 200 73941
remote - - [31/Dec/1994:23:55:08 -0700] "GET 45.html HTTP/1.0" 200 5489
remote - - [31/Dec/1994:23:56:55 -0700] "GET 2195.ps HTTP/1.0" 200 522318
remote - - [31/Dec/1994:23:59:37 -0700] "GET 957.ps HTTP/1.0" 200 122146
remote - - [01/Jan/1995:00:31:54 -0700] "GET index.html HTTP/1.0" 200 2797
remote - - [01/Jan/1995:00:31:58 -0700] "GET 2.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2555
```

Comment: what you trying to find in log file???, what is ur expected output

Comment: Web server hits results:

    ('Jan', 43666)
    ('Feb', 72114)
    ('Mar', 99761)
    ('Apr', 65011)

Comment: You said in a comment below, **"I did not write the code."**  If the code is not your own work, you should say so by citing the author and title of the original work, and by linking to the original if it's (legally) available on the Web.  Whether or not a full attribution is a legal requirement (it might be, but I'm no lawyer), it's basic courtesy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add

```
main()
```

or more formal:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

at the end of your source code and run again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Signare:  This actually _does_ answer "why this code produces no error messages and no output" --- it's never run.  If it were, @user4745212 would be asking us why he's getting a `SyntaxError` or maybe an `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: @Signare: I take back the `SyntaxError` claim --- it came from my old Python 2.6 installation.  `{key,values}` is legal in 3.x and maybe 2.7... although it's a set, and not the dictionary he wanted.

Comment: thanks. stupid mistake. but data {key,values} gives unbound error in ipython.    It works with python 2.7 with or without key,values in the data tuple

Answer (score 0):

As flycee has pointed out, you don't appear to be *running* this code.  (Or did you just not post the call to `main`?)

You have other problems... The first line of `main`:

```
data = {key,values}
```

You clearly intended `data` to be a dictionary, so that comma should be a colon:  `{key: values}`.

A bigger problem is that the two variables inside the set / dictionary --- `key` and `values` --- haven't been defined yet.  This would raise an `UnboundLocalError` if it were ever executed.

Other problems...

- In `main`, you set `idx` to the log file's line number (0-indexed), and pass it to `mapper` as the `key` argument.  `mapper` never *uses* its `key` parameter, so you're effectively creating the `idx` value just to throw it away.
- `reducer` likewise doesn't use its `key` parameter, but at least it doesn't throw it away completely.  Still, there's no reason to feed `main`'s `key` to `reducer` just to get it back unchanged.
- `mapper` returns a `None` that will later get used as a key in a dictionary that is otherwise keyed only with strings.  Either return an empty string (`""`) in place of the `None`, or --- better still --- make sure the return value `is not None` before adding it to the dictionary.  You said you wanted to count months like `"May"` and `"Dec"`... so don't pollute your data with all the not-months.
- `mapper` returns a tuple of two values, only one of which is of any interest.  The second value is always a `1`, and could not conceivably be anything *but* a `1`... even in the case where `mapper` finds nothing.  So just return the interesting part: the string `"Jan"` or `"Oct"` or whatever.
- Using `sum` on a list of tens of thousands of elements is overkill when you know in advance that every element is a `1`.  Use `len` instead.
- Using `len` on a list of tens of thousands of elements is overkill when you know in advance that the list exists *solely* to count something.  Use an
  `int` instead.
- Implementing a counter from several different functions is overkill when the Python standard library already gives you one for free.  Use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead.

A final quibble:  Your `mapper` isn't really mapping anything, and the only reducing in your `reducer` is the built-in `sum` function.  So why not call `mapper` something more meaningful like `month_logged`, and replace `reducer` entirely with `sum`?

Comment: I did not write the code.  This code is meant to demonstrate the hadoop map reduce concept using python.  This is the error message with ipython notebook , if data{key value}: UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-79ec3eb644ff> in <module>()
     20         for key, values in data.items():
     21             print reducer(key, values)
---> 22 main()
Code runs with python 2.7 -----
---------- If you have a better solution please post it as I am only a beginner with python.  Thanks.

Comment: @user4745212:  That `UnboundLocalError` is exactly the error I said you'd get on that line: you're attempting to use the `key` and `values` variables before they've been defined.  That would be an error anywhere.  Since you will be adding the data you want to the dictionary as you go, it seems silly to initialize it with any contents at all --- start with `data = {}` instead.